# What's the performance impact of running mongodump?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodump

What's the performance impact of mongodump util?

- Will write operations be blocked while mongodump is running?
- Will read operations be blocked/significantly slowed down?

I cannot find any official docs about its behavior, so I'm curious in someone's real-world experience of dumping big DB on the fly.

Comment: This is more of an operative question than a development question, so it would fit much better on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated the question for migration.

Comment: The [Behaviour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#behavior) section of the official documentation broadly covers your essential questions. You are probably IMHO better served by searching the web for "mongodb backup strategies" or similar for various options and performance comparisons.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I can see the only sentence "When used in combination with fsync or db.fsyncLock(), mongod will block reads, including those from mongodump, when queued write operation waits behind the fsync lock." It's still not clear for me.

Comment: There's a similar and very good discussion here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76130/16127

Comment: I'd also suggest reviewing [DBA: Mongodump affects app performance really bad](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156197/9345). `mongodump` won't block write operations, but can have a significant performance impact (particularly if your data is much larger than available RAM) as all data has to be read into memory by the MongoDB server.